# Not able to upload an EAR file in WAS 7.0.0.35

Tags: ant, websphere, ear

I am trying to upload and install an EAR file in WAS 7.0.0.35 but getting the following exception -

The EAR file could be corrupt and/or incomplete. Make sure that the application is at a compatible Java(TM) Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) level for the current version of WebSphere(R) Application Server.
com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException [Root exception is org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: dd_in_ear_load_EXC_]

below is the ant task which i am using to generate the EAR file

```
<target name="EAR" depends="WAR">
    <war destfile="${build.dist}/ddp.war" webxml="${web.xml}">
        <fileset dir="${WebContent}" />
        <classes dir="${thinx.classes}" />
    </war>
    <ear destfile="${build.dist}/ddp.ear" update="true" appxml="${application.xml}">
        <fileset dir="${build.dist}" includes="**/ddp.war" />
    </ear>
</target>
```

Application.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application id="Application_DD_ID" version="5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd">

    <display-name>
    ABCDDDP</display-name>
    <module id="WebModule_91234567812345">
        <web>
            <web-uri>DDP.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/DDP</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

I am able to upload and deploy the war file and it is working fine. Please suggest me what is the correct way to generate the ear file in this case.

Comment: This is a known poor error message.  There should be a better message in a "Caused by" in either the SystemOut.log or wsadmin.traceout depending on how you're trying to install.

Comment: Just a guess, but I see ddp.war in lower case while building EAR and DDP.war in the application.xml, maybe try to fix that and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks Gas. It is working now. It was the lowercase uppercase issue. Thanks for figuring it out.